# visual basic - WriteLine with 2 or more colors?

Tags: vb.net, console

I want to put different colors to 'melon', 'cherry' and 'apple' in my string:

```
My favorite foods are: melon, cherry, apple
```

I only know:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
Console.WriteLine("line here")
```

But that will change the whole line to red, not only one word.

I also found this on a question here in StackOverflow:

```
Private Shared Sub colorize(ByVal expression As String, ByVal word As String)
    Dim substrings() As String = expression.Split()

    For Each substring As String In substrings
        If substring.Contains(word) Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    End If
    Console.Write(substring &" ")
    Console.ResetColor()
    Next substring
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
```

The one above works well, but what it does is find the matches of `word` in your line, then colors all the results with the specified `ForegroundColor`, so it does not work when there are two or more same words in your line and you want those words to have different colors.

Most of what I find were in C#. Is there any way in VB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use WriteLine, you can just use Write.

```
    Console.Write("My favorite foods are: ")

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    Console.Write("melon")

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.Write(", ")

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed
    Console.Write("cherry")

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.Write(", ")

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    Console.Write("apple")
```

I don't know what are your input so it's hard to help more. But I hope this will give you an idea on how to proceed.